# Write a mouseover function using prototypejs

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to re-write the following jquery code using prototypejs. How can I do that?

```
<a  class="btn" id="control" href="javascript:control();">Control</a>

$('#control').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $('#bg2').css({
            background: '#F93'
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: Post a snippet of what you tried before asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('control').observe('mouseover', function(event) {
  $('bg2').setStyle({
      background: '#F93'
  });
});
```

You can find all the information here:

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/setStyle/